# mod_proxy missing in apache2 installation

Tags: installation, apache2, hhvm

I have an issue with my apache2 configuration for HHVM.
I'm on Debian 7.

The problem is verry simple : mod_proxy are missing in my apache2 installation (/etc/apache2/mod-availables/).

I've reinstall apache2 a several time but nothing do to mod_proxy is still missing, i've try to enable it manually but still the same error.
I must have the mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi files !

Here is the error :

> apache2: Syntax error on line 249 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot
>   load modules/mod_proxy.so into server:
>   /etc/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

My apache2.conf is unchanged.

Here is my etc/apache2/sites-available/hhvm.conf

```
ServerName hhvm.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/dev

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.(hh|php)(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/dev/$1 retry=0
```

The last solution i still have is to compile from source apache2 ...